# Error while configuring Virtual Machine role in Failover Cluster

Tags: hyper-v, failovercluster

After restart my Windows server 2012 R2, when I am trying to add new Virtual Machine in Failover cluster by using configure role and then select Virtual Machine role then I am getting the below error:

```
The operation has failed.
An error occurred while determining the state of this cluster role in the cluster.
One or more error occurred.
Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005(CO_E_SERVER_EXE_FAILURE))
```

I tried to add Virtual Machine in failover cluster from other nodes of the cluster but on other nodes also getting same error.